# Reading versus Opening in Python

Tags: python

For an assignment I created a piece of code.
The goal is to open a file and find the email addresses from the senders.

```
#open file
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)


#look for the appropriate lines and add the in a list
names = []
for line in fh:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("From:"):
        words = line.split()
        names.append(words[1])
```

My question would be: Why does

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)


#look for the appropriate lines and add the in a list
names = []
for line in fh:
line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("From:"):
        words = line.split()
        names.append(words[1])
```

work but

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) < 1 : fname = "mbox-short.txt"

fh = open(fname)
text = read.fh()


#look for the appropriate lines and add the in a list
names = []
for line in text:
line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("From:"):
        words = line.split()
        names.append(words[1])
```

won't?

I'm having trouble to understand why I should use only open and not read.

Thanks

Comment: `text = read.fh()` is wrong. Use `fh.read()`

Comment: It doesn't work because `read.fh` is completely nonsensical. It also won't work because you would no longer iterate over lines, but over individual characters. And most important, "doesn't work" is not an acceptable error description on SO. Please re-take the tour and read through the help center before any further interaction with this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to replace, `read.fh()` with `fh.read()` because `read` hasn't been defined and `fh` is the file object you want to read from.

Second, the problem is fh.read() returns a string, not a list of lines. Thus when you iterate over you are doing it by character. This is not what you want.

If you want to use fh.read(), then you must split `text` by lines. So use `text.split('\n')` in your for loop, instead of text.

Comment: The more problematic thing is the completely messed up attempt at calling `read`...

Comment: @l4mpi, you are right. I have expanded my answer to address that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I managed to solve it but I was wondering why the read did not work. Understanding why something doesn't work is equally important in my learning process. Thank you very much.